# QQuickWidget Custom Resizing Mode

Tags: c++, qt, qml, resize, qquickwidget

**Note:** This a self answered question. It cause me some headache to solve it in past, so I think it is worth to share.

I have a qml application designed for HD resolution(1366x768). It's using `QtQuick.Layouts`, so adaptable to custom resolution. But resizing it to less than HD resolution makes it squishy and meaningless. I am not restricting `QQuickWidget`'s size with minimum size, cause now I'm trying to place multiple of them in grid layout of a `QWidget`. I want to scale down root item to fit in widget when size of `QQuickWidget` is less than initial size(1366x768). Problem is `QQuickWidget` offers only two [ResizeMode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwidget.html#ResizeMode-enum) options and none of them suits to my needs. And it is not possible deactiave `ResizeMode`. So I'm trying to disable `ResizeMode` and write a custom one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kinda ugly but working solution. I checked the [source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/quickwidgets/qquickwidget.h.html) of `QQuickWidget`, and realized inner [updateSize](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/quickwidgets/qquickwidget.cpp.html#783) function does nothing when [ResizeMode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwidget.html#ResizeMode-enum) is invalid.

```
CustomQuickWidget(QWidget* parent = nullptr)
    : QQuickWidget(parent) 
{
    //set invalid resize mode for custom resizing
    setResizeMode(static_cast<QQuickWidget::ResizeMode>(-1));
    setSource(QML_SOURCE);
}

void CustomQuickWidget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) {
    QQuickWidget::resizeEvent(event);

    const int eventWidth = event->size().width();
    const int eventHeight = event->size().height();
    const int initialWidth = initialSize().width();
    const int initialHeight = initialSize().height();

    if (eventWidth >= initialWidth && eventHeight >= initialHeight) {
        // SizeRootObjectToView
        rootObject()->setSize(event->size());
        rootObject()->setScale(1);
    }
    else {
        // Scale down
        const qreal widthScale = qreal(eventWidth) / initialWidth;
        const qreal heightScale = qreal(eventHeight) / initialHeight;

        if (widthScale < heightScale) {
            // stretch height to fill
            rootObject()->setWidth(initialWidth);
            rootObject()->setHeight(qMin(int(eventHeight / widthScale), maximumHeight()));
            rootObject()->setScale(widthScale);
        }
        else {
            // stretch width to fill
            rootObject()->setWidth(qMin(int(eventWidth / heightScale), maximumWidth()));
            rootObject()->setHeight(initialHeight);
            rootObject()->setScale(heightScale);
        }
    }
}

QSize CustomQuickWidget::sizeHint() const { return initialSize(); }
```

Make sure [transformOrigin](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#transformOrigin-prop) of root item is `TopLeft`.

```
transformOrigin: Item.TopLeft
```